# SRT socket connection time out

Tags: ios, objective-c, sockets, protocols

I'm facing an issue while connecting to socket on my local server, Where i am getting an error of connection time out (1001) shown in attached screen shots.

Is there any default SRT socket address and port using which i can test my code on connection socket?

Here is my code

```
- (IBAction)onSender:(id)sender {
    int yes = 1;

    const char ipAddress [] = "192.168.112.45:8000";
    
    printf("srt startup\n");
    srt_startup();
    
    printf("srt create socket\n");
    srtSocket = srt_create_socket();
    if (srtSocket == SRT_ERROR)
    {
        // fprintf(stderr, "srt_socket: %s\n", srt_getlasterror_str());
        [NSException raise:[@(srt_getlasterror(nil)) stringValue] format:@"%s", srt_getlasterror_str()];
    }

    printf("srt bind address\n");
    struct sockaddr_in socketAddrIN;
    memset(&socketAddrIN, 0, sizeof(socketAddrIN));
    socketAddrIN.sin_family = AF_INET;
    socketAddrIN.sin_port = htons(1234);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ipAddress, &socketAddrIN.sin_addr);
    
    printf("srt set socket flag\n");
    srt_setsockflag(srtSocket, SRTO_SENDER, &yes, sizeof(yes));
    
    printf("srt connect\n");
    int result = srt_connect(srtSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&socketAddrIN, sizeof(socketAddrIN));
    
    if (result == SRT_ERROR) {
        // fprintf(stderr, "srt_connect: %s\n", srt_getlasterror_str());
        [NSException raise:[@(srt_getlasterror(nil)) stringValue] format:@"%s", srt_getlasterror_str()];
    }
    
    srt_close(srtSocket);
    
    srt_cleanup();
}
```

Error log
[image]

Answer (score 0):

int network_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

```
        struct sockaddr_in socketAddr;
        socketAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        socketAddr.sin_port = kSocketPort;
        socketAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        
        int result = connect(network_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&socketAddr, sizeof(socketAddr));
        
        if (result == -1) {
            NSLog(@"Connection failed");
            return;
        }
        
        close(network_socket);
```

Comment: Maybe your port is wrong！8000 and 1234 need the same！

Comment: i tried this but did not get any success.

Comment: will you please provide a sample code related to SRT connection. that would be more better